# How To Link To A Frame Adobe Flash CS6 Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

i need help with my adobe flash assignment , i m still new to adobe flash :( how to tell the user if they input the wrong keyword how to link them to a frame .

```js
var i:int = 0;
var names:Array = new Array("html","head","body");
var frames:Array = new Array("6","7","8");

searchhtmlll.text ="";

searchhtml.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_2);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 findInArray(searchhtmlll.text);
 gotoAndStop(frames[i]);
}

function findInArray(str:String):int
{
 for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
 {
  if(names[i] == str)
  {
   return i;
  }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering based on whatever limited information you have provided in your question, and from what I understand.

Your method `findInArray` has a return type of `int`, where as you are just calling it without assigning it to a variable.

So your code should be:

```
var result:int = findInArray(searchhtmlll.text);
gotoAndStop(frames[result]);
```

Hope this helps.